# Why does Dropbox break my Drupal site?

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-7, dropbox

I'm using Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 and Drupal 7.  I wanted an easy remote backup for my Drupal site, so I tried putting it in Dropbox.  Then, something happened, and Apache started giving 403 errors ("You don't have permission to access / on this server.") for the site.

I recovered from an old backup, but I still can't figure out what happened.  I diffed the Dropbox directory and the backup, and they're the same.  I reset all the permissions in the Dropbox directory to match the backup, but the version in Dropbox still won't work.  I also tried copying the files from the Dropbox directory into the location of the backup, and that still didn't work.

I'm a bit at a loss as to what went wrong.  Does anyone have ideas as to what Dropbox might have broken?

Comment: So, it's a bit unclear reading your problem, did you remove files from your server, did you copy files to dropbox, then from dropbox, copy them to your server?

Comment: On my server, I moved files from ~/foo to ~/Dropbox/foo (and updated the Apache config accordingly).  It was serving properly when at ~/foo,  then it broke sometime after being moved to ~/Dropbox/foo.  Moving the files back from ~/Dropbox/foo to ~/foo didn't fix things.  I did not remove files or copy new files to the server.

Comment: Dropbox may, or may not alter files; of that I'm unsure; I can only relate a personal experience that at one point, I offered a download to a friend, and it tripped their browser's virus alarms.  I tried a different method, and that method worked fine.  Otherwise, I don't have much to contribute, here.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to run the site from a Dropbox location, why not just make Dropbox the repository for backups?

Try this:
https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate_dropbox
This will also backup your database which you didn't mention as part of your Dropbox backup strategy.

Or you could run a cron task to run incremental backups via rsync to the Dropbox folder (Assuming you have already gone through getting Dropbox connected any syncing with Ubuntu).  I use the process documented at this location and it has worked perfectly on a number of different web servers:
http://hadzimahmutovic.com/rsnapshot-mysql/rsnapshot-backing-mysql-databases